# Strict validation for latin character set (ISO 8859)

Tags: python, validation, iso

I'm looking to validate user input to ensure that all characters in the input string fall within the western-latin character set.

## Background

I'm specifically working in Python, but I'm looking more to understand the ISO-8859 character set than receive actual Python code.

For a simpler example of what I'm looking for, if I was looking to ensure that user input was entirely ASCII, I could easily do so by checking that each character's numeric value falls in the range [0-126]:

```
def is_ascii(s):
    for c in s:
        if not (0 <= ord(c) <= 126):
            return False

    return True
```

Simple enough! But now I want to validate for ISO-8859 (western latin character set).

## Question

Is this a simple case of changing the upper bound for the value of `ord(c)`?

If so, what value should I replace `126` with?

If not, how do I perform this validation?

## Note

I'm expecting to receive characters that are certainly outside of ISO-8859, for example emotes entered from a mobile device's keyboard.

## Edit

After some further research it looks like replacing `126` with `255` would potentially be a valid solution, but I would appreciate if anyone could confirm this?

Comment: If you look at the [table for ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout), you'll see that it's a simple range with just a couple of holes in it.

Comment: P.S. Make sure you perform this test on a Unicode string.